# issue with PHP PDO code won't execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

am making comment system for my website forum and I want  to insert the new comment into the forum comment table in my DB am sure that the code being, using
to insert the code in my table is correct but still not working

```
 **// function to submit users replies to the topics** 
function replayTopic($conn,$errors,$success){
    **// get the topic link from the page link**    
    $topicLink = $_GET['name'];

    **// check if the submit button is clicked**
    if (isset($_POST['topicReplay'])) {
        **// get the user id from the session**
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        **// get the comment from the textarea** 
        $replay = $_POST['commentPost'];
        **// get the topic id** 
        $getTopicId = "SELECT topicId FROM topics WHERE topicLink = :topicLink";

        if ($topicStmt = $conn->prepare($getTopicId)) {
            $topicStmt->bindParam(':topicLink',$topicLink);

            **// execute the query above**
            if ($topicStmt->execute()) {

                **// fetch the data from the query above**
                if ($topicRow = $topicStmt->fetch()) {
                    **// apoint the topic id to the topicId var**
                    $topicId = $topicRow['topicId'];
                    **// inert the comment into the forum comment table**
                    $insertComment = "INSERT INTO 'forumcomment'                                   
                                        (comment, commentDate, commentBy, topicComment) 
                                      VALUES
                                        (:replay, NOW(), :userId, :topicId)";

                    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($insertComment)) {
                        **// bind the placeholders from the insert query**
                        $stmt->bindParam(':replay', $replay);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':userId', $userId);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':topicId', $topicId);

                        **// for some reason the query above won't execute**
                        if ($stmt->execute()) {
                            echo "string";
                        }else{
                            echo "not working";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the front end of the code am, using

```
<?php echo '<form action="'.replayTopic($conn,$errors,$success).'" class="mt-4" method="POST">';?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="replays">Comment </label>
        <textarea name="commentPost" id="replays" cols="30" rows="6" 
        class='form-control'></textarea>
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-4 ml-auto">
        <button class="form-control btn btn-success w-100" type="submit" name="topicReplay">Replay</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 mr-auto">
<li class="form-control btn btn-link text-right" id="cancel">Cancel</li>        
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am sure that all of the variables are correct. I tried to echo all of them. 
I go throw this 10 times till now and I couldn't find whats wrong with this code.

Comment: So you call your function and add some `echo` inside and you get all your `$_POST` value?

Comment: yes I got all of the echoes inside my function

Comment: That cannot be, the two echos that are there are mutually exclusive. Which PDO code won't execute? You have two `execute()` in your code.

Comment: I have two execute the select statement execute and the insert execute the one not working is the insert execute

Comment: So you've echoed `$topicId` and it show and has a value?

Comment: On a side note: singular of replies is `reply`, not `replay`.

Comment: if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($insertComment)) {
 **// bind the placeholders from the insert query**
$stmt->bindParam(':replay', $replay);
$stmt->bindParam(':userId', $userId);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':topicId', $topicId);

                        **// for some reason the query above won't execute**
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
  echo "string";
  }else{
                            echo "not working";
                        }

Comment: yes I echoed the $topicId and it showed a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your INSERT statement isn't working because you're delimiting the table name with `'` instead of `` ` ``. Try this instead:

```
$insertComment = "INSERT INTO `forumcomment`                                   
    (`comment`, `commentDate`, `commentBy`, `topicComment`) 
    VALUES
    (:replay, NOW(), :userId, :topicId)";
```

Comment: I tried a lot of thing bro and this was one of them and nothing happened my code still won't execute

Comment: Well, the quotes were certainly a problem.

Comment: Have a look at PDO error handling: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: well it worked when I removed all the quotes and deleted the forumcomment table and created it again now the code work fine thanks for the help

Comment: @AwadGorg Maybe one of the column names was slightly different. For future, you generally delimit table and column names when you have a case sensitive RDMS and you need to pass names with mixed case. Hence why you see a lot of databases using snake case, to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: for some reason, the code worked when I dropped the DB table and created it again
the first time I insert data into the tale was from the phpmyadmin directly should this be the reason cause I’ve noticed that every time I insert data into one of my tables from the phpmyadmin it stop insert data from the PHP code any idea why this happening

Comment: @AwadGorg you're also mixing `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. What is probably happening is you are processing a post request, but because you try to get the topiclink name, that comes through blank, which results in a null topicID. Instead of `$topicLink = $_GET['name']` try `$topicLink = $_POST['name']`.